# Changing roof truss diagonal to vertical

Tags: roof, structural, truss

I've got a roof with a few diagonal trusses like the blue one in this diagramme:

[image: BLUE is existing truss, RED is proposed]

I want to remove the BLUE truss and replace it with the RED truss, because we're adding some loft storage and currently have to climb over the blue trusses to move around.

Three important notes:

1. The right most vertical beam ends above a wall, whereas the proposed red beam would end only on the supporting beam.
2. The truss supports lightweight roof sheeting in tin or aluminium. There's nothing else on the roof.
3. I live in South Africa, where there's some wind and some rain, but no snow.

Is there anything very critical I should beware of, or should I avoid doing this entirely?

Comment: It does not look like a good idea. Where the original gets its support is at the wall. The bottom piece only needs to support itself. Changing the bracing would then place the added weight of the roof onto the lower piece. The drawing only shows the pieces... not the dimensions or grade of lumber, nor the spans of any of the members. All this factors in how a structure withstands loads.

Comment: Please give us the size of the 3 members, the span of the horizontal member, and the spacing of the trusses.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything very critical I should beware of, or should I avoid doing this entirely?

Yes, you should be aware that the roof truss wasn't haphazardly designed by someone on a Friday at 4:59 PM.

A lot of engineering went into your trusses so unless you're an engineer then I would suggest you do not alter the webs.